# Calling a function with setContentView(R.layout) from another function?

Tags: java, android

When I call `dbconctfun(view v)` method through onclick threads and runnable code it is executing last after executing other code in the `dbconctfun(view v)` method. In the console it shows:

```
out of loop   out of loop
test#######   multiple class.forname
queryexct     queryexct
```

My code:

```
package com.example.loginandroid;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.os.Looper;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    String username,password;     ResultSet rs =null;
    boolean temcfag=false,temqfag=true;
    public static String tag="Lifecycle activity";
    EditText user,pass;
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        dialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        dialog.setNeutralButton("OK", null);


        user=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    }

    Thread  thrd1,thrd2,thrd3;
    Connection con;
    String result ="",queryexct;

    public void dbconctfun(View v )  throws SQLException {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             Log.v("test#######","multiple class.forname");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        thrd1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    }
                    if (con == null) {
                        try {
                            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://111.111.11.11:6666/dyne", "root1", "mysql");
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            con = null;
                        }

                        if ((thrd2 != null) && (!thrd2.isAlive()))
                            thrd2.start();

                    }
                }

            }
        });
        if ((thrd1 != null) && (!thrd1.isAlive())) thrd1.start();

        thrd2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (!Thread.interrupted()) {

                    if (con != null) {
                        if (temqfag) {
                        try {
                            Statement st = con.createStatement();
                            username=user.getText().toString().trim();
                            password=pass.getText().toString().trim();
                            queryexct="SELECT * FROM  `user_registration` WHERE  `email_id` =  '"+username+"' AND  `password` =  '"+password+"'";
                            rs = st.executeQuery(queryexct);
                            Log.v("queryexct","queryexct");
                            temqfag=false;
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            con = null;
                        }

                        try {
                            Log.v("test#######","errorrrrrrrrrrr3");
                            if (temqfag) {Thread.sleep(10);}
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }}
                    } else {
                        try {
                            Log.v("test#######","errorrrrrrrrrrr4");
                            Thread.sleep(300);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        });
        Log.v("out of loop","out of loop");
        if(rs!=null){
            if (rs.next()) {
                Log.v("test#######","errorrrrrrrrrrr1");
                Looper.prepare();
                Thread.interrupted();
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
                Log.v("test#######","errorrrrrrrrrrr1");
            }
            else{
                Log.v("test#######","errorrrrrrrrrrr2");
                Thread.interrupted();
                Looper.prepare();

                dialog.setMessage("Your username and password are not valid");
                dialog.show();


            }
        }
        temqfag=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please rewrite your question without all capital letters?

Comment: I have two comments on your code unrelated to your question. On the line where you defined "queryexct" you are opening yourself up to SQL injection. Also, it looks like you're storing a password in the database as plaintext. These are both security problems. SQL injection allows anyone to run any SQL on your database: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection And storing plain text passwords means that a security breach will reveal your users' passwords: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=216

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i didn't exactly get what are you trying but from what i understand if you are trying to change the layout using threads then you won't be able to do that because it is only possible on main thread.

Comment: when i call dbconctfun(view v ) method it executing last lines of code first and first lines of code last of this method.

Comment: I guess your first line of code is making thread to sleep that's why it's executing the later part.

Comment: can't i stop code to not execute remaining code when thread is sleep

Comment: then put whole code in same thread.

Comment: i am not able to change layouts and putting dialog messages in threads.showing errors you cant keep views in thread runnable

Comment: That's the whole thing bottom line is you can't do any thing related to user interface in the threads. But what you want to do can be achieved using async task. Calculate what you want in the background process and then display it in post execute method. Your answer is ASYNC Task study about it.

Answer (score 0):

The setContentView is a function of your activity.

So you need to invoke it like this from other funciton:

```
 MainActivity.this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
```